# How to disable ssl on particular url on nginx

Tags: nginx

I need help with some nginx configuration. So please help. So here is my situation.

my domain: rtechmedia.com

1) I want all the request of http:// www.rtechmedia.com redirect to https:// www.rtechmedia.com

2) I want all the request of https:// rtechmedia.com to https:// www.rtechmedia.com

3) But i want that the style folder and its content located at www.rtechmedia.com/styles/* should redirect to http:// www.rtechmedia.com/styles/* instead of https:// www.rtechmedia.com/styles/*

I am noob in nginx so please give in details. And note i put space in url because of low reputation. So ignore it

I am able to achieve 1) and 2) but not 3 so help me with that.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.rtechmedia.com;
    return 301 https://www.rtechmedia.com$request_uri;

}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name rtechmedia.com;
    return 301 https://www.rtechmedia.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.rtechmedia.com;
    root /home/forge/www.rtechmedia.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.rtechmedia.com/11369/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.rtechmedia.com/11369/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.rtechmedia.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: redirect how? server-side rewrites would be pointless, and client-side redirects would just lead to a ton of security warnings due to mixing ssl-content with non-ssl-content.

Comment: I know but i will using cdn and will replace the styles/* path with cdn https url but cdn need http to access get content from origin